# Died in war for saving own country, will he be considered as martyr?

Tags: practical-islam, jihad, war, martyr

If someone muslim in military died in war for sake of saving their country. Will they considered as (Many people claim) martyr? And will they get paradise for that?

Comment: Martyrs are those who die for the sake of Allah, not for something other than Allah. Read wikipedia article "Shahid" and hadith collections (Fighting for the cause of Allah).

Comment: Today these kinds of questions might be very subjective. As a martyr -especially of this kind- should die for the cause of Allah that might be the intention of some of individual soldiers, but generally they follow the orders of their commandants which don't necessarily are fighting for such a big cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A martyr is a *Muslim who gets killed in combat against the disbelievers*. Such a person will be called and treated as a martyr in at least this life, such as in the funeral rites.

In order to be a martyr in the sight of Allah, and hence be granted paradise, his intentions must be pure. His goal must have been the dominance of Islam and defeating of Kufr, not some worldly ambition or value. He must have been killed while fighting or advancing and not while fleeing or deserting. He must not have stolen from the spoils of war.

> #### جاء رجل إلى النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم، فقال الرجل: يقاتل للمغنم، والرجل يقاتل للذكر، والرجل يقاتل ليرى مكانه، فمن في سبيل الله؟ قال: من قاتل لتكون كلمة الله هي العليا فهو في سبيل الله
>
> A man came to the Prophet (ﷺ) and asked, "A man fights for war booty; another fights for fame and a third fights for showing off; which of them fights in Allah's Cause?"
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "He who fights that Allah's Word (i.e. Islam) should be superior, fights in Allah's Cause."
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/56/26)</sup>

A soldier fighting for his country may or may not be a martyr. You can judge his worldly status by applying the criterion above. And Allah will judge his status in the afterlife by applying the criterion above.

Answer (score 1):

It’s all about their intention. Whoever sacrifice their Life for the sake of Allah swt will consider as a martyr. We can see some arab countries fighting for their nation freedom still they’re fighting to the enemies of islam. So in that case we can call them martyr. And the reward of martyr is giving ALLAH azwajal.That’s why i said it’s about their intention.